# Return parent post with its children using WP_Query?

Tags: wp-query, wp-list-pages

In some cases it might be useful to use multiple post & page parameters in your `WP_Query` object. In my case, I would like to display children of a parent page including the parent page itself.

Visualization of what I want to achieve. Imagine the following pages hierarchically sorted as following:

- page A
- **page B**

  - **Child page A**
  - **Child page B**
  - **Child page C**
- page C

The **bold list items** are the posts/pages I want to retrieve.

My first thoughts go out using these two parameters for `WP_Query`:

```
$args = array(
   'post_id' => $parent->ID,
   'post_parent' => $parent->ID,
);
```

Unfortunately, here it will only use one parameter. With the `$args` above (correct me if I'm wrong) it will output all children posts of the parent post and **not** the parent post itself as well.

This problem might be solved by gathering all posts needed and putting them in parameter `post__in` like so:

```
$args = array(
   'post__in' => $children_and_parent_ids,
);
```

However there is [`wp_list_pages()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/) allowing you to `include` a post(s) and specify the post where you want to include the children of (`child_of`). Why is this not possible with `WP_Query`?

An example of what I'm trying to achieve using `wp_list_pages()`:

```
wp_list_pages(array(
    'include' => $parent->ID,
    'child_of' => $parent->ID,
));
```

Have a look at [the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) of `WP_Query`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can filter the `posts_where` clause of the generated SQL to also return the parent post/page and not just the parent's children. Here we will set our own custom argument called `wpse_include_parent`, which, when set to `true`, will alter the generated SQL accordingly.

All we need to do inside our `posts_where` filter is to check if our custom argument is set and that the `post_parent` argument is set. We then get that value and pass it to the filter to extend our SQL query. What is nice here, `post_parent` excepts a single integer value, so we only need to validate the value as an integer.

### THE QUERY

```
$args = [
    'wpse_include_parent' => true,
    'post_parent'         => 256,
    'post_type'           => 'page'
    // Add additional arguments
];
$q = new WP_Query( $args );
```

As you can see, we have set `'wpse_include_parent' => true` to "activate" our filter.

### THE FILTER

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', function ( $where, \WP_Query $q ) use ( &$wpdb )
{
    if ( true !== $q->get( 'wpse_include_parent' ) )
        return $where;

    /**
     * Get the value passed to from the post parent and validate it
     * post_parent only accepts an integer value, so we only need to validate
     * the value as an integer
     */
    $post_parent = filter_var( $q->get( 'post_parent' ), FILTER_VALIDATE_INT );
    if ( !$post_parent )
        return $where;

    /** 
     * Lets also include the parent in our query
     *
     * Because we have already validated the $post_parent value, we 
     * do not need to use the prepare() method here
     */
    $where .= " OR $wpdb->posts.ID = $post_parent";

    return $where;
}, 10, 2 );
```

You can extent this as you need and see fit, but this is the basic idea. This will return the parent passed to `post_parent` and it's children

Comment: The code works, but unfortunately it returns two times the same parent post. When running a `WP_Query` with the custom attribute.

Comment: I retested my code and I cannot replicate your issue

Comment: have a look at [my code and output](http://pastebin.com/w6bRavcr). Hopefully this will make you understand the problem better. Try to put the query on the parent or child page itself.

Comment: I had a look at the `var_dump()`. There are two posts returned in `$q->posts`, post ID's 2126 and 2116, which seems to be correct, no duplicate post there. I think what you are seeing is post 2116 also available in `$q->post`, which is also correct. That is the `$post` global value for that specific query and will always be the first post in `$q->posts` by default

Comment: Okay but it is always is returning two parent posts, even when viewing the child post with this code of this parent (so the `global $post` contains the child post object). The question is why is it iterating 3 times when there are only 2 posts to iterate through?

Comment: *why is it iterating 3 times when there are only 2 posts to iterate through* That has got nothing to do with the query then. In the query object, there are two posts. If there is a third post, it is injected into this query via some custom filter. Everything in your query looks OK, although the SQL query looks funny due to some other filters working on the query. You should debug this, make sure `$post` is what you expect it to be, is your loop correct, are the other filters used used correctly in context. On a vanilla install, everything works on my side as intended.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot help you here because, as I said, everything works on my side as intended. Start by deactivating plugins, dump all your variables and make sure they are what they should be, and switch to a bundled theme

Answer (score 6):

If all you want is results from the "page" post_type then do as @birgire suggested.

Alternatively you can adapt the following to give you a similar result for not only the `page` `post_type` but any custom post type.

```
$parent = 2;      //change as desired
$type   = 'page'; //change as desired

$child_args = array( 
    'post_type'   => $type, 
    'post_parent' => $parent 
);

$ids = array( $parent );
$ids = array_merge( $ids, array_keys( get_children( $child_args ) ));

$query = new WP_Query( 
    array( 
        'post_type'      => 'page', 
        'post_status'    => 'publish', 
        'post__in'       => $ids, 
        'posts_per_page' => -1 
    ) 
);
```

The above is essentially the same thing as hooking onto the `posts_where` filter and parsing the SQL clause however, this achieves exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
        'orderby' => 'ID',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post_parent' => $postID,
    );

    $children = new WP_Query($args);
    $parent[] = get_post($postID);
    $family = array_merge($parent, $children->get_posts());
```

This seems to work. Comments?

Comment: True, but it won't be as efficient as the accepted answer. The accepted answers approach only requires one query to be executed, your approach will result in two queries being executed (if not already cached).

Comment: I think your answer is much better !!!
so much more simple/readable !!! And to save what... 1 query ? out of 100s in WordProut context... and it's been cache 30 time before it got to your code....

on top of that the save query is one `WHERE ID=123` .... 0.0001s

Answer (score 0):

Using `global $wpdb` combined with `[get_results()][1]` is an option as well. Performance wise I think this is the best solution since it only runs one query.

Here is my final code.

```
<ul class="tabs"><?php

    global $wpdb, $post;

    $parent = count(get_post_ancestors($post->ID))-1 > 0 ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID;

    $sql = "SELECT ID FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}posts`";
    $sql.= " WHERE ID='{$parent}' OR post_parent='{$parent}' AND post_type='page'";
    $sql.= " ORDER BY `menu_order` ASC";

    $tabs = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

    $output = '';
    foreach ($tabs as $tab) {
        $current = $post->ID == $tab->ID ? ' class="active"' : '';

        $output .= '<li'.$current.'>';
        $output .= empty($current) ? '<a href="'.get_permalink($tab->ID).'">' : '';
        $output .=   get_the_post_thumbnail($tab->ID, 'menu-24x24');
        $output .=   '<span>'.get_the_title($tab->ID).'</span>';
        $output .= empty($current) ? '</a>' : '';
        $output .= '</li>';
    }
    print $output;

?></ul>
```

Comment: You would think that would be the case, however `WP_Query` under the hood will cache query results, so for example, a call to `get_children()` or `get_post_ancestors()` in addition to `WP_Query` should not include any additional performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to get the ID's of both the parent and any subsequent children pages. Wordpress has functions that fetch the children of pages, such as this one:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_children

It is my understanding, that since you are performing a WP_Query, you are already fetching the ID's of the parent pages, so all you would need to do is pass in the relevant ID to the the above function to get what you desire.

Note: I should point out that this function doesn't do a DB query, so better performance wise as you are only making on query to the DB.

Comment: I understand why you mention this function but, this answer is more a comment then an answer. Anyway I can't find a reason why this function could be useful since `WP_Query` already allows you to specify to a list of a post it's children with the argument: `post_parent`. So why is this function not deprecated?

Answer (score -2):

You can use `get_pages()` with `child_of` parameter like below :

```
<?php
   get_pages( array(
     'child_of' => $parent_page_id;
   ) );
?>
```

Comment: That's not what I want to achieve, I don't want to use `wp_list_pages` because the output isn't fulfilling my needs.

Comment: See my updated answer. Hope this will help to you.

Comment: Thank you for the update, unfortunately this doesn't include an explanation on how to include the parent post.

Comment: you can refer https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages for detailed explanation

Comment: According to the documentation: `The child_of parameter is not applied to the SQL query for pages. It is applied to the results of the query`. As well as it won't return the parent.