# Get post and its children with WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, wp-list-pages

I want the parent post *and* its children posts. I don't know the parent post ID, only that its `post_password` field is not empty.

It's very similar to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/221485/return-parent-post-with-its-children-using-wp-query) except the post ID is *not* known in my case.

[image: list of posts in the database with post parent and its children highlighted]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question that is similar to your question, i took sample code from there. you can replace 'post_parent with this.

```
global $post;
$args = [
    'wpse_include_parent' => true,
    'post_parent'         => wp_get_post_parent_id( $post->ID ),
    'post_type'           => 'post'
    // Add additional arguments
];
$q = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This code will get the parents post id when you are inside children post